# How to disable menu under ALT+1 binding in Linux-Mint

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to disable the menu in Linux-Mint which is showing when you press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. I can't even capture the screen when the menu is showing so I've attached a photo. I tried everything and I didn't find the answer how to disable it. Any sugestions?

[image]

EDIT:

The solution posted below by @tohuwawohu works perfect on Linux Mint 15 and 16, but doesn't work on my computer with Mint 13 (Maya). I'm still looking for a way to disable the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open exactly that menu -> `System` -> `Preferences` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts` -> `Desktop` -> `Show the panel's main menu` and use backspace to delete the shortcut (or assign any other shortcut).

Comment: It's very strange. I have ALT+F1 not ALT+1 assigned to this action on my ultrabook. The problem occurs on the computer at work, so if removal this action will help I will definitely accept your answer. On my ultrabook this problem doesn't occur so I'm unable to test it at the moment.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot accept this answer. Maybe in most cases it will work, but I have the "Show the panel's main menu" set as "Disabled" but the ALT+1 shortcut still triggers the menu. Any idea how to solve this? I'm using Linux Mint Maya 13.

Comment: @toro: I'm sorry that the proposed solution doesn't help - i will try to set up a VM with Maya this weekend. Please tell me which desktop (Mate, KDE, Xfce, Cinnamon) you're using.

Comment: I'm using Mate.

Comment: You could try `mateconf-editor` to search the config. Menu `Edit` -> `Find` or CTRL+F will open the search dialogue. Search for the String `<Alt>1` (with `Search also in key values` selected) to find all keybindings involving `ALT+1`. HTH!

Comment: I tried this before with gconf-editor and nothing was found, this is why I wrote "I tried everything and I didn't find the answer how to disable it." Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't how but the issue is now fixed. I just updated my linux. In most cases your solution will work so I can accept it now.